# How to fix this reverse function so it doesn't stack overflow?

Tags: prolog

I got this reverse function from http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse25:

```
accRev([H|T],A,R):-  accRev(T,[H|A],R). 
accRev([],A,A).

rev(L,R):-  accRev(L,[],R).
```

This works for things like

```
?- rev([a,b,c], R).
R = [c,b,a]
```

But I get a stack overflow with this:

```
?- rev(L, [c,b,a]).
```

Why does this cause a stack overflow? Is there a way to make both work?:

Answer (score 4):

> `?- rev(L, [c,b,a]).`
>
> Why does this cause a stack overflow?

Sssh... you are revving the Prolog engine.

Actually, two reasons: First, the query does not terminate. And then, it searches solutions in a rather ineffective manner.

Let me "solve" this problem, by addressing the second reason first. Just exchange the two clauses of `accRev/3`. This changes the answer from:

```
?- rev(L, [c,b,a]).
   resource_error(_). % ERROR: Out of local stack
```

to

```
?- rev(L, [c,b,a]).
   L = [a, b, c]█
```

nice - or almost. Note that Prolog did not put a `.` at the end of the solution. That means it says: Want more of this? So by typing `;` you get:

```
?- rev(L, [c,b,a]).
   L = [a, b, c]
;  resource_error(_). % ERROR: Out of global stack
```

So we "almost" solved the problem. We found a solution, but Prolog still does not terminate. This illustrates nicely one property of pure Prolog programs:

> Exchanging clauses may influence how solutions/answers are found, but it does not affect termination.

The best way to ensure that a goal actually terminates is to "switch off" all the answers we get by adding `false`:

```
?- rev(L, [c,b,a]), false.
   resource_error(_). % ERROR: Out of global stack
```

This error now occurs in the very same way no matter how the clauses are arranged. In fact, the cause can be narrowed down to the following [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice):

```
rev(L,R):-
   accRev(L,[],R), false.

accRev([],A,A) :- false.
accRev([H|T],A,R):-
   accRev(T,[H|A],R), false.
```

Note the `R` which is simply passed further on.  It thus has no influence on termination whatsoever.

Observe, however, that the length of `L` and `R` are the same ...

So maybe consider `same_length/2` first, it could solve this directly.

```
same_length([], []).
same_length([_|L], [_|R]) :-
   same_length(L, R).

rev_better(L, R) :-
   same_length(L, R),
   rev(L, R).
```

Or, if you are into "efficiency", just observe that `same_length/2` can be folded directly:

```
rev_folded(L, R) :-
   accrev(L, [],R, R).

accrev([], R,R, []).
accrev([E|L], R0,R, [_|Rx]) :-
   accrev(L, [E|R0],R, Rx).
```

Comment: Still learning prolog, so I am having a bit of trouble digesting all of this.

Failure-slice seem a bit odd. From my understanding, when we say:

some_function(A) :- Set A to 0,

Comment: @Jean: When we say what?